# How to fix the wrong identification on commits from GitHub desktop?

Tags: github, github-for-mac

Even though I have connected my account to GitHub desktop, commits I make from there are somewhat not linked to my account.

[image: Here is an example screenshot]

I also should indicate that email I am using GitHub Desktop with has the same email with my account (@kutayeroglu)

Thank you for your time and answers!

Comment: Do you want to change the owner of commits ?

Comment: Yes, specifically I want 'Kutay' to be linked to the account 'kutayeroglu'. When I look at my profile from the browser, no commits can be seen under my account "kutayeroglu"

Comment: Check the answer on Atlassian : https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/how-do-you-make-changes-on-a-specific-commit-779171729.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the exact solution to my question. However, here is my new method which prevents this error;
Firstly, I use terminal instead of GitHub Desktop. (Using terminal really allows me to better understand git structure. Highly recommended.)

1. Use "`git init`" in the file you want to create a repository in.
2. Set up information with the following commands. E-mail and the username you enter here should be the same with your GitHub account.

   git config --global user.name "kutayeroglu"
   git config --global user.email "kutay@example.com.tr"

Hope this helps anyone having a similar problem!